# What are the ways application may die?

Tags: linux, signals

I develop linux daemon working with some complex hardware, and i need to know ways how application may exit (normal or abnormal) to create proper cleanup functions. As i read from docs application may die via:
1. Receive signal - `sigwait`,`sigaction`, etc.
2. `exit`
3. `kill`
4. `tkill`

Is there is some other ways how application may exit or die?

Comment: `_exit()` comes to mind. And `abort()`

Comment: And the `exec()` functions of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you wrote that you're concerned about "abnormal ways" the application may die.

There's only one solution for that<sup>1</sup> -- code outside the application.  In particular, all handles held by the application at termination (normal or abnormal) are cleanly closed by the kernel.

If you have a driver for your special hardware, do cleanup when the driver receives notification that the device fd has been closed.  If you don't already have a custom driver, you can use a second user-mode process as a watchdog.  Just connect the watchdog to the main process via a pipe... it will receive a signal when the main application closes.

---

In addition to things the programmer has some degree of control over, such as wild pointer bugs causing segmentation fault, there's always the oom-killer, which can take out even a bug-free process.  For this reason the application should also detect unexpected loss of its watchdog and spawn a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should finish by itself when the system or the user doesnt need it.

Using an external commando like a kill -9 PROCESS could give you some bugs on your application because you don't know what is your application doing in that moment.

Try to imeplement over your app a subsystem to control your application status... like a real daemon to allow something like this:

```
yourapp service status  or  /etc/init.d/yourapp status
yourapp service start  or  /etc/init.d/yourapp start
yourapp service stop  or  /etc/init.d/yourapp stop
```

In that way your app could finish normally everytime and the users could control it easily.

Regards

Comment: I have a script wrapper in /etc/init.d that does exactly what you write via start-stop-daemon, but i need to know some abnormal ways when application may die.